# Classification accuracy won't improve when running Keras example Image Classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have been trying to train image classification networks (ResNet, EfficientNet, etc.) from the Keras Applications, both from scratch and only fine-tuning the final layers. What became very quickly obvious is that the classification accuracy would never increase beyond average.

Because of this, I ran the current [example image classification from scratch](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/#train-the-model), with no modifications beyond removing the graph visualisation. The first error is that instead of 1590 images being deleted, only ~1573 images were removed. This means the training process contains repeated warnings of:

```
Corrupt JPEG data: 2226 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
```

On top of this, after training for four epochs, the training summary (without interruptions and errors) looks something like this:

```
Epoch 1/50 586/586 [==============================] - 67s 115ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.5013 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.4957
Epoch 2/50 586/586 [==============================] - 66s 113ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.5018 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.4957
Epoch 3/50 586/586 [==============================] - 67s 114ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.4988 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.4957
Epoch 4/50 586/586 [==============================] - 66s 112ms/step - loss: 0.6932 - accuracy: 0.5007 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.4957
```

Obviously, val_loss shouldn't be nan either, but this may be due to the corrupted images (albeit when trying to use the same architecture on my own files earlier that *also* returned nan for val_loss; although with the Applications models it had no such problem), albeit why only some of them weren't deleted is its own problem.

TensorFlow posts its own GPU-related warnings at the beginning of execution, but this doesn't appear to contain any errors or missing files beyond the warning about GPU asm compilation:

```
2020-10-24 04:10:48.280970: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-10-24 04:10:51.609522: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-10-24 04:10:51.632770: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:26:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3090 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.725GHz coreCount: 82 deviceMemorySize: 24.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 871.81GiB/s
2020-10-24 04:10:51.632983: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-10-24 04:10:51.635721: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-10-24 04:10:51.638327: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-10-24 04:10:51.639159: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-10-24 04:10:51.642240: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-10-24 04:10:51.643877: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-10-24 04:10:51.650449: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-10-24 04:10:51.650630: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-10-24 04:10:51.650971: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-10-24 04:10:51.657923: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1d05d9b2b20 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-10-24 04:10:51.658087: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-10-24 04:10:51.658285: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:26:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3090 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.725GHz coreCount: 82 deviceMemorySize: 24.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 871.81GiB/s
2020-10-24 04:10:51.658507: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-10-24 04:10:51.658625: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-10-24 04:10:51.658732: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-10-24 04:10:51.658844: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-10-24 04:10:51.658957: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-10-24 04:10:51.659077: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-10-24 04:10:51.659189: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-10-24 04:10:51.659321: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-10-24 04:10:52.605664: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-10-24 04:10:52.605785: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
2020-10-24 04:10:52.605853: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N 
2020-10-24 04:10:52.606081: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 21823 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 3090, pci bus id: 0000:26:00.0, compute capability: 8.6)
2020-10-24 04:10:52.608550: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1d0145ef0b0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-10-24 04:10:52.608715: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce RTX 3090, Compute Capability 8.6
2020-10-24 04:10:55.807657: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-10-24 04:10:56.537098: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-10-24 04:10:58.860654: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/redzone_allocator.cc:314] Internal: Invoking GPU asm compilation is supported on Cuda non-Windows platforms only
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. 
Modify $PATH to customize ptxas location.
This message will be only logged once.
```

Further code that produces the same inability to improve accuracy, regardless of optimizer or hyperparameters:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental import preprocessing as p

bs = 32  # batch size
train_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
    "E:/Images/Cropped",
    seed=1337,
    validation_split=0.1,
    image_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=bs,
    subset="training"
)

validation_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
    "E:/Images/Cropped",
    seed=1337,
    validation_split=0.1,
    image_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=bs,
    subset="validation"
)

train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
train_ds = train_ds.repeat()

# input block
start = keras.Input((224, 224, 3))
pre = p.Rescaling(1./255)(start)

# main block
base = EfficientNetB0(
    include_top=False,
    weights="imagenet",
    input_shape=(224, 224, 3)
)

base.trainable = False
x = base(pre)

#new head
top = keras.layers.AveragePooling2D()(x)
top = keras.layers.Flatten()(top)
top = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(top)
# top = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(top)
top = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax")(top)

model = keras.Model(inputs=start, outputs=top)

model.summary()

opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01)
# opt = keras.optimizers.Adam()

model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=validation_ds, epochs=750, steps_per_epoch=128, batch_size=bs, verbose=1)
```

As far as I can determine, there should be no problems with the code in either case (one is obviously example code), and no obvious errors in the installation; everything at least runs. But nothing diverges from the average accuracy for the number of classes.

**Edit:** After running [this mnist convnet on CPU and GPU](https://keras.io/examples/vision/mnist_convnet/) it appears that the error is GPU related, with the CPU training being correct and the GPU training also having errors.

It may be related to this line:

> tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/redzone_allocator.cc:314] Internal: Invoking GPU asm compilation is supported on Cuda non-Windows platforms only
> Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation.
> Modify $PATH to customize ptxas location.

However, the only solution I've found for running GPU code appears to be to downgrade the TF version entirely.

Comment: Where did you get the data from? Have you tried downloading it again and then training the model?

Comment: https://download.microsoft.com/download/3/E/1/3E1C3F21-ECDB-4869-8368-6DEBA77B919F/kagglecatsanddogs_3367a.zip As linked in the example page. Deletes 1578 images after redownloading, same as the first time and not the 1590 it should; accuracy still hovers at the 50% mark, val_loss is still nan. @yuRa

Comment: Why are you deleting some of the images?

Comment: See example page; some of the images are required to be deleted because they contain incompatible data. My first codeblock highlights what happens when the images are *not* deleted--every epoch is full of multiple lines like that warning of extraneous bytes. Regardless, even if all the images were correctly defeated, it doesn't seem like that would be responsible for why completely different data and models also have the same unmoving accuracy (image crops from ImageNet ILSVRC 2012); only as an example that it's likely not code-related, as it's from Keras example code. @yuRa